# Rails JS conditionally display div based on the radio button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
$('.domestic_select, .abroad_select').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    if($(this).val() == "true") {
      $('#customer_goods').show();
      $('#state_field').show();
      $('#country_field').hide();
      $('#change_resident').show();
    }
    else {
      $('#change_resident').hide();
      $('#customer_goods').hide();
      $('#country_field').show();
      $('#state_field').hide();
    }
  });
```

```
.fieldset
        .row
          .col-sm-12
          = f.label :pin_code,"Pin Code", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
          = f.text_field :pin_code, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
          %div{id: 'state_field'}
            = f.label :state,"State", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
            = f.select(:state, options_for_select(State.collect_state),{},{class: "selectpicker col-sm-3", id: "myselect", prompt: "Select State", "data-live-search": "true"})
          %div.hide{id: 'country_field'}
            = f.label :country,"Country", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
            = f.select(:country, Country.collect_country,{}, {class: "selectpicker add_class_country dropdown_country col-sm-3", title: "select country", "data-live-search": "true"})

      %br
```

Here I've hidden the country div, so that the state field is being displayed initially. when clicked the abroad option the "country div" should be displayed and "state div" should be hided

But what I got is both state and country fields are hidden after selecting the abroad option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How have you hidden `#country_field` initially. `display: none;`? You need to make sure that you are using display: none and not visibility: none; or some other styling as jquery uses, display: none/block; to hide and show.

```
$('.domestic_select').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#customer_goods, #state_field, #change_resident').removeClass('hide');
    $('#country_field').addClass('hide');
  }
});

$('.abroad_select').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#customer_goods, #state_field, #change_resident').addClass('hide');
    $('#country_field').removeClass('hide');
  };
});
```

Comment: Yes, I need to hide #country_field initially. so that state field will be displayed at initially.once i click the abroad option in dropdown it should replace the state field with country field. I've hided country div just using "%div.hide{id: 'country_field'}" .can u help some more?..thank u in advance

Comment: So you are using a dropdown not radio buttons? I don't understand what `%div.hide{id: 'country_field'}` means, is that supposed to be haml. If so, what styling is assigned to the `.hide` class? Is it using `display: none;`?

Comment: im using radio button to be selected and the fields to be displayed are dropdowns.im not using any styling. just used div.hide in haml. it is used to hide the div. so i need to show it using JS based on the condition

Comment: div.hide will have css styling if it's actually hiding the content. Right click on the page and inspect it then find the hidden element and view the css in the right hand column of the inspector.

Comment: It is working.thank u very much.i've inspected that class and and now only i get to know about that its a style.anyway thank u!